# Duplicate questions in feed, and questions incorrectly marked as unanswered

Tags: bug, ios-app, unanswered-questions, ios-app-feed

> [image: Feed Bug]

I see duplicate questions in the feed (Why is the book still wanted if Aida has memorized it?) and the question is marked as "unanswered" even though it has an upvoted answer.

I would expect unique questions in the feed, as well as questions with answers to not be marked as unanswered.

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: @Iain the question had an answer with 6 upvotes. I have edited my report for clarity.  While what you said may be true, it's not relevant to the issue reported.